# Practicing Writing Fork Processes using close() and open() functions

Tags: c, fork, system-calls

I'm practicing writing fork processes and I got stuck in the area where parent passes the process off to the child. I seem to get a bit lost there.

I was thinking the child opens `/dev/null` and then writes a lot of data to this file. Each iteration of the loop writes 10 bites to `/dev/null`.

More specifically I want to write a 10-character array and run the loop a bunch of times like 100,000,000 iterations!

In the meantime the parent will be in standby mode until the child process has finished. This is what I currently have:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int fd = open("/dev/null",O_WRONLY);

  pid_t newPid = fork();
  if (newPid <0) {
    perror("fork() failed");
    exit(1);
  }
  if (newPid > 0) { //Parent
    pid[procIdx] = newPid;
  } else { //Child
    //write 10 bytes to /dev/null
    write(fd, "ABCDEFGHIJ", 10)
    exit(0);
    close (fd);
  }
  // Wait for processes to complete
  for (int i = 0; i < // unsure what to write here; i++) {
    if (waitpid(pid[i], NULL, 0) == -1) {
      perror("waitpid() failed");
      exit(1);// process termination status value 1
    }
  }
  exit(0); // process termination status value 0
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. We don't know what are `pid` and `procIdx`.

Comment: pid[] table is not defined. If you have only one process, why do you need pid[] ? When the child calls exit(0), it is useless to call close(fd) behind it as exit() is a no return call (it finishes the calling process). A simple waitpid(newPid, ...) would be sufficient in the father to wait for its unique child.